# GNU Grub 2.01 won't load in 19.04

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, 19.04

After having problems with 18.02.2, I reformatted hard drive and loaded 19.04 with USB flash drive. Installed and also did updates. At first wasn't able to live boot flash drive (to use gparted), then checked BIOS and found that I could load UEFI PXE first (this was not an option previously), so did that and was able to use flash drive boot and 'Try Ubuntu' to partition hard drive (I hope). Now grub doesn't load. Instead of grub menu, I get "grub>" and "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else, TAB list possible device or file completions."
Tried to boot using flash drive again (and making it boot first in BIOS), but still get the same unhelpful screen. Tried 'boot' and was told "you need to load the kernal first".
Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Sort of fixed. I disabled the hard drive and re-installed Ubuntu from the flash drive at boot. Of course all the partitions I made were lost and am not confident that the flash drive will boot and let me recreate them. This machine seems to object to booting from a flash drive after installation.

Comment: Confirm that flash drive will not boot, although it is first in bios boot. Might have to disable ubuntu (hard drive) again to enable this, so I can partition hard drive (although this is may not work). UEFI option has disappeared in bios boot options. Not getting grub on boot either - any grub - but at least not getting grub terminal. System boots directly into ubuntu. Worse than before.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Wrote the 19.04 iso to a dvd on a Windows computer. Took a few minutes, but it created a live start-up disc. Then put it into the Ubuntu computer and changed the bios to make it boot first using the UEFI option which appeared. The dvd booted live - this took some time, so patience is needed - but once I got the live environment, I was able to use gparted to partition the hard drive. I then rebooted and removed the disc and confirmed in Disks that the partitions were recorded. They were. Onward now

Comment: So on your computer a USB won't work but a DVD will?

Comment: That's right. The flash drive only worked for the initial installation. Took me a week and several reinstallations and reformattings to discover that detail, since I didn't have a live dvd. Also in 18.04 I wasn't able to write to a dvd, so just in case, I created the live boot dvd on a Win8 machine. I haven't tried to write to dvd in 19.04 yet, but the bios recognizes a dvd, so hopefully will work. This is a brand new Acer XC-830-EB11. I installed Ubuntu on a new hard drive rather than try to double boot with Win 10.